# How do I convert raw bits stored in a unsigned integer type to a signed value without encountering undefined or implementation-defined behavior?

Tags: c, embedded

I have an embedded device producing a stream of bits which I receive stored in an array of `uint_16`s. I know that the 16 bits at a particular offset are actually a 2's compliment binary number. i.e. an `int16`.
What is the best way to interpret these bits as an signed number that doesn't invoke undefined or implementation-defined behavior.

Given `uint16_t data[N];`:

```
int16_t value = (int16_t)data[offset];
```

Works on my platform, but is definitely implementation defined.

```
union {  int16_t value; uint16_t raw } u;
u.raw = data[offset]
int16_t value = u.value;
```

Also works, but is also implementation defined, as far as I know.

What about this?

```
int16_t value = *(int16_t*)&(data[offset]);
```

I'm having trouble finding a clear standards-based answer for the best practice here.

Answer (score 4):

Converting through a union is not implementation-defined. Per the C standard, reading a union member other than the last one read reinterprets the bytes, and the value bits of corresponding integer types must represent the same values. So `(union { uint16_t u; int16_t i; }) {data[offset]} .i` gives the `int16_t` value represented by the bits of the `uint16_t` `data[offset]`, with no undefined or implementation-defined behavior.

Another solution is:

```
#include <stdint.h>


//  Convert a uint16_t to the int16_t represented by the same bits.
static int16_t ConvertUInt16ToInt16(uint16_t u)
{
    /*  int16_t is specified to be two’s complement.  So we will interpret the
        most significant bit as -32768 instead of 32768: If the high bit is set
        (representing 32768 in a uint16_t), we subtract 65536 (thus yielding a
        net interpretation of -32768, its value in two's complement).  We also
        cast to int32_t to ensure the expression remains within bounds.  Then
        we return the result (which is automatically converted to the int16_t
        return type, which does not change the value since it is representable
        in int16_t).
    */
    return u - ((int32_t) u >> 15 << 16);
}


#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


static void Test(uint16_t x)
{
    int16_t Expected = (union { uint16_t u; int16_t i; }) {x} .i;
    int16_t Observed = ConvertUInt16ToInt16(x);
    if (Expected != Observed)
    {
        printf("Error with 0x%08" PRIx16 ":\n", x);
        printf("\tExpected %" PRId16 " but observed %" PRId16 ".\n",
            Expected, Observed);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    Test(0);
    for (uint16_t i = 1; i; ++i)
        Test(i);
}
```

Apple Clang 11.0 actually fully analyzes this program at compile time and compiles it to a program that immediately returns success without any looping and run-time testing:

```
_main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```

Comment: thanks for this. Can someone point to the standard reference on unions?