# What is the safest and most well-defined way to perform narrowing type conversions with signed integers in C?

Tags: c, type-conversion, portability, signed, type-narrowing

I have read: [What happens when I assign long int to int in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13652556/16217248)

```
int64_t x;
int32_t y;

y = (int32_t)x;
```

According to the answer and to the C standard if I try to assign, for example, a `signed long` to a `signed int` and the value does not fit, the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

To solve this poorly defined behavior I thought about using unsigned types first:

```
y = (int32_t)(uint32_t)(uint64_t)x;
```

But this is no good either because like with converting larger integer types to smaller ones, converting an unsigned integer to a signed one will result in an implementation-defined value or signal if the value does not fit.

I would like to perform narrowing conversions such as unsigned to signed or a larger signed integer to a smaller one, in a way that does not invoke implementation defined behavior, and will simply preserve the bit representations (this should give very predictable and well defined results as long as the sign representation is as expected). Is there any way to do this with casts? Will I have to use a `union` like so?

```
union Cast {
    int32_t i32;
    int64_t i64;
};
y = ((union Cast){.i64 = x}).i32;
```

Will that even work (i.e. guarantee that `y` simply contains the exact bit pattern as the lower 32 bits of `x`)? As a last resort will `memcpy()` have to be used and will that work?

**Edit:** Turns out using the above `union` will not be portable because whether that gets the upper or lower 32 bits depends on whether the system is big or little endian. However if I use this:

```
union Cast {
    int32_t i;
    uint32_t u;
};
y = ((union Cast){.u = (uint32_t)x}).i;
```

Would that be portable?

**Note:** This question was asked out of curiosity, and the fact that many times, for diverse reasons, I want to safely truncate the bits of a signed integer.

Comment: If you have a large value that you want to assign to a variable that can't hold such a large value, there's no cast or conversion that can solve that problem. You will always loose data in such a conversion. If you only want the low 32 bits of your 64-bit value, then do a bitwise mask and do an explicit conversion of the *result*. Like e.g. `y = (int32_t) (x & 0xffffffffllu)`.

Comment: Regarding your union, will the `i32` member get the high or low 32 bits of the `i64` member? That's not well-defined.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm okay with the losing data part, but not the implementation-defined behavior part. If the bitmask includes the sign bit, and the sign bit is set, and I assign that to the smaller type, it could still not fit because a positive value could 'become' a negative value and thus invoke the implementation-defined conversion.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh yes, I now realize the union depends on the endianness of the implementation.

Comment: It feels like there's an underlying problem you want to solve, but we can't help you solve that problem because you don't tell us about it. If this is just for curiosity then please [edit] your question to tell us. Otherwise ask about the actual and underlying problem directly, telling us about your proposed solution. If you don't do that then your question unfortunately becomes an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is for curiosity, and the fact that many times, for diverse reasons, I want to safely truncate the bits of a signed integer.

Comment: Note: C23 mandates two's complement representation for integer types. You might want to get a copy of the standard, and see if narrowing conversions are defined now.

Comment: @user3386109 But if it's not a trap representation, is it well-defined?

Comment: @user3386109 I think when I write my code, there's a line to draw when it comes to whether an implementation is worth supporting or not. And where I personally draw that line is 'not two's complement.' Good idea, maybe I should go to bed too, it's almost midnight.

Comment: I think using a union for type punning signed and unsigned "exact width" integer types of the same width (e.g. `int32_t` and `uint32_t`) is portable as long as the implementation supports the exact width integer types in question. (The exact width integer types are optional, but the most common systems support exact width 8-, 16-, 32- and 64-bit integer types.) They are guaranteed to have a 2's complement representation and no padding bits, therefore no trap representations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to perform narrowing conversions… in a way that… will simply preserve the bit representations (this should give very predictable and well defined results as long as the sign representation is as expected).

Well, that is on the right track, but it is missing something: You did not say what sign representation is expected. An expert tip for writing specifications is to actually specify what you want.

Let’s say you want two’s complement, because it is the most popular representation scheme. Equivalently, given some integer *x* you want to convert to a signed *N*-bit integer format, you want a result *y* congruent to *x* modulo 2<sup>*N*</sup> with −2<sup>*N*−1</sup> ≤ *y* < 2<sup>*N*−1</sup>.

The `intN_t` types are guaranteed to use two’s complement and have no padding bits (C 2018 7.20.1.1 1). So, if you can get the low bits of *x* into a `intN_t`, you are done. (I will also note that given a signed integer type and its corresponding unsigned integer type, the standard requires that their corresponding value bits represent the same value, in C 2018 6.2.6.2 2.)

You cannot rely on a union with a wider type because the C standard does not specify the order of bytes in storage, so you do not know, from the C standard alone, which bytes of the wider type contain its lower bits. We can work around this easily by converting the value to a `uintN_t` first. The conversion from integers out of range of an unsigned type to the unsigned type is fully defined by the C standard; it wraps modulo 2<sup>*N*</sup>, producing a result in [0, 2<sup>*N*</sup>).

Here we perform that conversion and use a union in a compound literal to reinterpret its result with two’s complement:

`(union { uintN_t u; intN_t i; }) {x} .i`

Although C++ is not mentioned in the question, I will note that reinterpreting via a union is not defined by the C++ standard. An alternative is to copy bytes:

```
uintN_t u = x;
intN_t i;
memcpy(&i, &u, sizeof i);
```

Both of these are portable to any implementations that support the desired fixed-width types.

This can also be done using arithmetic rather than reinterpreting bytes. Say we are converting from some wider type with *M* bits. First we can cast to `uintN_t` to get the low bits. Then we can adjust the value represented by bit *N*−1: `((uintN_t) x ^ ((intM_t) 1 << N-1)) - ((intM_t) 1 << N)`. That arithmetic is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74520257/how-do-i-make-a-16-bit-integer-into-a-9-bit-2c-number-in-c/74520544#74520544).

We can also use:

```
uintN_t u = x;
intN_t i = u - (intM_t) u >> N-1 << N;
```

That arithmetic is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72386405/how-do-i-convert-raw-bits-stored-in-a-unsigned-integer-type-to-a-signed-value-wi/72386615#72386615).

Comment: How about `_Static_assert(-1==~0, "Not two's complement");`